# fork() and wait() in c while loop?

Tags: c, fork, wait, pid, wexitstatus

I have this small program in c and I am trying to understand how it works, it is a simple while loop that uses `fork()` and `wait()` to print out a few lines on the command line, I have commented to the best of my ability what I think is happening

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)            /*simple while loop, loops 3 times */
{
    pid = fork();                   /*returns 0 if a child process is created */
    if(pid == 0){                   /*pid should be a 0 for first loop */
        printf("Hello!\n");         /*we print hello */
        return (i);                 /*will this return i to the parent process that called fork? */ 
    }   else {                      /*fork hasn't returned 0? */
        pid = wait(&j);             /*we wait until j is available? */
        printf("Received %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(j));   /*if available we print "received (j)" */
    }
}
```

This program is supposed to print:

```
Hello!
Received 1
Hello!
Received 2
Hello!
Received 3
```

When one of the child processes returns `i` does the parent process wait for it as `&j`? This is really confusing me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fork()` isn't `pthread_create()`, so `return`ing from the function that called `fork()` doesn't necessarily terminate the process. Post *all* of the relevant code.

Comment: See [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait). Everything is explained there ...

Comment: the function: fork() has three possible return states '-1' when an error occurs, '0' if executing child and some positive number when executing parent.  The posted code is not handling the error return.

Answer (score 7):

In each iteration of the loop `fork()` creates a child process. The
   child process prints `Hello!` and returns `i` to the system. The
   parent process blocks on `wait()` until child finishes execution.
   `j` will contain the value that the child process returned to the system.

Comment: That's great, really gives me a good way to visualize how the code is working, thanks :)

Comment: It should be noted that even though the child process returns an `int`, only the least significant byte is made available to the parent process waiting on the termination status. Furthermore, this value must be fetched with `WEXITSTATUS()` (as shown in the code), but it is only safe to do so when `WIFEXITED()` returns true (which the code fails to do).